# How to make realistic light emission effect using EEVEE nodes with detail

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, glass, emission, glare

I saw on Blenderartists a user who made traffic lights and have good detail, looking realistic using EEVEE render engine. I have included some images from the internet which show the lights having detail and also some emission.

My Attempt to make it look realistic with plain emission is lacking details.
The traffic light men, seen in orange and Green, seem to have a blend of colours giving making them seem more real world reflective and emitting light out of the glass somehow.

You will see my bulbs are just emission colours with HDRI world which do have reflections, but the emission of the colours are lacking detail, like the last image with the RED X, which looks bland.

Someone please show me a node set up for better result?

https://blenderartists.org/t/traffic-lights-in-eevee/1163866

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try with a simple node setup, instead of a glass material, I've mixed a *Transparent* with a *Glossy*, with a *Layer Weight* as *Factor*, and also add a *Translucent*. You can make it more complicated of course, with some *Noise Texture* plugged into the *Glossy* and *Transparent* for example. The filament has an *Emission* shader with a *Strength* that is more than 1 so that the *Bloom* effect can work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks looks great!

regards.